# Cannot insert encrypted text into sql

Tags: php, ssl

I'm currently in php using the openssl_public_encrypt method to encrypt a message that is sent to the server using GET(this is just a proof of theory), and if I attempt to store the encrypted text into the database I end up getting the result: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax" even though this error does not occur with plaintext.

Code used to generate key:

> ```
> $config = array(
> "digest_alg" => "sha512",
> "private_key_bits" => 4096,
> "private_key_type" => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA,
> );
> ```
>
> // Create the private and public key
>      $res = openssl_pkey_new($config);
>
> // Extract the private key from $res to $privKey
>      openssl_pkey_export($res, $privKey);
>
> // Extract the public key from $res to $pubKey
>       $pubKey = openssl_pkey_get_details($res);
>       $pubKey = $pubKey["key"];
>
> openssl_public_encrypt($message, $encrypted, $pubKey);
>       $sql = "INSERT INTO `na14_messaging`.`messages` (`To`, `From`, `For`, `message`) VALUES ('$To',       '$From', '$For', `$encrypted`)";

Example of encrypted string: 
@aú¡±ñþú]Ð½¾ÄÉçù\dgQppx+Þ˜ŽüÑzXê+¡™½ºWÏãÐ£ú]¢c—Ä‘õ›µCŽ{¶f¶³”câÂ“,hK‹á[àžÑõ~Ÿ-ëòqÊ"ÏAÁ{™OMu£öÈåmL¶9j½m¨eë]|ñN šÈo|"˜û®AûÉ{q¤<’ˆVÿ ¤û*.÷+j'iâÜËu_öSÏ˜þHX_Îƒâñ'ÎãDÌÛóê²¿2¾GÀ5ûÃ'á©« ™®`§=¹0åÿŸ¦ácü¤l¼ÛmÚ!ysŽH2È«\­šP÷ÒÕˆ.ºjôÊEŠ»™’LrñboïVÜ¶ÓFw~3‡ÛŽ.Z,?:îawxRã^˜>:µ-áÒ‘<ûQ8‚•"ÕC9Ç[\£vU¶°6‡Þts<Çg¢8Y8›$c˜­"•;ï>Ñ¾)„fá+ž ™ØÓ•¿¼€äF£Þ\ZjxÂS#þ³”"zÇù Áçd¥qw‚mn$eî’ $•Ñæ6Ð ½žS™ÕÍPƒuâÛŸ%‘o7b¯gŸ»D[³%ådKÁ·¶ Et×y    ©[˜Û•g@?°Ü÷§Ý±  ³Õßý‹¸Åå¡Ð{(Ö‘f;w–3ïMkHÿÇùÒ1•ÏåÜ

I'm assuming it's just the characters that's causing the error of putting this into the Database, I've tried varchar, longtext, and blob. I'm not sure what data type would work for this.

Comment: Please show your code? It sounds like you're not using parametrized statements or escaping the string.

Comment: It turns out that I did longtext again and now it works, I don't know why but hell if it works it works

Comment: @user2636072 maybe it works now maybe not. how many "\X00" bytes are there in that encoded data.

Comment: Turns out that fix only works in certain cases, it's the fact that openSSL will add ' and other characters, thus it escapes the string etc. I've updated this with the code I'm using and hopefully that will clear up questions

Answer (score 0):

Changing the SQL variable back to longtext along with encoding to base64 has fixed all issues that occur.